# Обновление данных на JFrame

Tags: java, jdbc, jframe

Делаю программу для взаимодействия с базой данных. Рисую достаточно примитивную форму

```
public void reviewTable() throws SQLException {

        DatabaseConnector dbConnector = new DatabaseConnector(connectionURL, username, password);

        try {
            dbConnector.Init();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("Ошибка при подключении к базе");
        }

        OrderRunningTable orderRunningTable = new OrderRunningTable();

        orderRunningTable.addDate(dbConnector, "listOrdered");
        jTableRunningOrder = new JTable(orderRunningTable);

        scrollbarRunnungOrder = new JScrollPane(jTableRunningOrder);
        scrollbarRunnungOrder.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1500, 400));

        ActionListener actionListener = new AddListener();

        btnNewOrder = new JButton("Добавление заказа");
        btnNewOrder.setBounds(0,400,150,30);
        btnNewOrder.addActionListener(actionListener);

        btnEditOrder = new JButton("Изменение заказа");
        btnEditOrder.setBounds(160, 400, 150, 30);
        btnEditOrder.addActionListener(actionListener);

        mainActivity.add(btnNewOrder);
        mainActivity.add(btnEditOrder);
        mainActivity.add(scrollbarRunnungOrder);

    }
```

Написал обработчик для добавления заказов. Добавление заказа происходит в отдельном окне. После того, как данные о заказе добавлены в базу мне необходимо сделать так, чтобы данные на форме тоже обновились. Написал для этого также обработчик нажатия на кнопку

```
public class InsertListener implements ActionListener{

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            DatabaseConnector connector = new DatabaseConnector(connectionURL, username, password);
            try {
                connector.Init();
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            if (!phoneNumber.getText().equals("") &&
                    !FIO_Client.getText().equals("") &&
                    !dataOrderedExecution.equals("") &&
                    !startAdress.getText().equals("") &&
                    !endAdress.getText().equals("") &&
                    !idDriver.getSelectedItem().equals("")) {
                connector.updateQuery("insert into mytaxi.listOrdered set phoneNumber = \'" + phoneNumber.getText() +
                        "\', FIO_Client = \'" + FIO_Client.getText() +
                        "\', dataOrderedExecution = \'" + dataOrderedExecution.getText() +
                        "\', startAdress = \'" + startAdress.getText() +
                        "\', endAdress = \'" + endAdress.getText() +
                        "\', tariff = \'" + String.valueOf(tariff.getSelectedItem()) +
                        "\', idDriver = " + Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(idDriver.getSelectedItem())) +
                        ", status = \'" + String.valueOf(status.getSelectedItem()) +
                        "\', typeAuto = \'" + String.valueOf(typeAuto.getSelectedItem()) +
                        "\', cmoke = " + cmoke.isSelected() +
                        ", WiFi = " + WiFi.isSelected() +
                        ", animals = " + animals.isSelected() +
                        ", children = " + children.isSelected() +
                        ", cost = 0"  +
                        ", paid = 0");

                connector.updateQuery("update mytaxi.autopark set status = \'Доезд\' where id = " +
                        Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(idDriver.getSelectedItem())));

                connector.finalize();



                try {
                    reviewTable();
                } catch (SQLException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
                newOrderActivity.dispose();
                newOrderActivity.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
            }
            else {
                JFrame error = new JFrame("Ошибка");
                error.setSize(100, 100);
                JTextArea errorsMessage = new JTextArea("Проверьте значения полей!");
                errorsMessage.setBounds(0, 40, 100, 20);
                errorsMessage.disable();
                error.add(errorsMessage);
                error.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
                error.setVisible(true);
            }
        }
    }
```

Данные в базе обновляются, а вот как обновить окно, в котором они отображаются? Попытался повторно вызвать метод reviewTable(), но безуспешно. Кроме того попробовал делать removeAll с mainActivity, также не помогает.

Comment: также пробовал методы repaint, updateUI

Answer (score 3, accepted):

попробуйте сделать так:

создаем окошко

```
JFrame window = new JFrame();
```

когда надо его обновить - чистим (возможно не полностью, но я полностью чистил),

добавляем по новой все что нужно и
 `.revalidate();`

```
window.getContentPane().removeAll();
window.add(что-то там);
window.revalidate();
```

Answer (score 0):

Делаем ваше окно невидимым:
frame.setVisible(false);
(здесь frame  это имя вашего окна)
а потом  сразу делаем окно видимым:
frame.setVisible(true);
Визуально окно как бы маргнёт, но
при этом информация в окне обновиться. Мне помогло при обработке событий по добавлению элементов (button) в окно. В окнах с графикой этот способ не поможет, при анимации например, необходимо старую информацию чистить или менять цвет старой позиции элемента на цвет фона окна, делая элемент в старой позиции
невидимым.

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
getContentPane().setVisible(false);
getContentPane().setVisible(true);
```

и будет без моргания окна, обновление отображения

Comment: Ответ дублирует уже имеющийся.